# DESCRIBE FIELD with an unassigned field symbol

Tags: abap

Here is one for you.

Why does the following piece of code not end with a short dump `GETWA_NOT_ASSIGNED` and instead return type `C` with length `2`?

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_any> TYPE any.

DESCRIBE FIELD <fs_any>
  TYPE DATA(l_type)
  LENGTH DATA(l_length) IN BYTE MODE
  DECIMALS DATA(l_decimals).
```

I could not find anything in the ABAP documentation about this behaviour.

EDIT:

It looks like the short dump is never to be expected. I tried it also with

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_any> TYPE i.
```

and

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_any> TYPE but000.
```

so [vwegert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218890/vwegert)'s answer looks to be plausible, because declaring a variable without any type like that `DATA: var.` defaults it to `c` with length `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personal opinion, not backed by documentation either: Since `DATA foo.` will create a variable of `TYPE C LENGTH 1` implicitly, this is what `DESCRIBE FIELD` does return in this case. You're probably on a Unicode system - on my system, it returns length 1. I'd say you've triggered some undocumented behavior, maybe even a bug. I'd strongly suggest **NOT** to rely on this - I suppose it might be changed at any time.

Comment: I can confirm that on our Unicode system it returns length 2. And it also returns the same value after UNASSIGN.